# Getting additional information during registration in MVC5 application

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Putting together an MVC5 application and what I would like to do is have a user either register as a client or a tradesmen. There login details can go into the same default [AspNetUsers] table that is created but if they are a tradesman I want additional details to be collected. When I look at some of the code that comes with the application I'm building I'm somewhat confused as to what I should do next or even if the approach I'm using is correct. I'm aiming to collect either set of registration information depending on which is filled in.

My account/register controller is beginning to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

                var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);                    

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (model.CompanyName.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        var company = new CompanyModel
                        {
                            CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                            AddressLine1 = model.AddressLine1,
                            AddressLine2 = model.AddressLine2,
                            Town = model.Town,
                            County = model.County,
                            Postcode = model.Postcode,
                            TelNo = model.TelNo,
                            MobNo = model.MobNo,
                            GoogleVerified = model.GoogleVerified,
                            FacebookProfileUrl = model.FacebookProfileUrl
                        };

                        //insert company details?
                    }                        

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

So my question would be is what I'm doing correct/a good thing to do, can I collect details for two types of user through the same Controller.

Also with the Register.cshtml page I have a jquery accordion, the idea being a client can fill in one section and join or a tradesman can click the accordion and it reveals another section to fill in. The problem I then face is I'm using this line of code once:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

{

Then sitting the accordion control inside this, which means I have these controls

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
```

Twice, once for a user and once for a tradesman, is this allowed?

Comment: Yes you can do it. I assume you mean you have 2 textboxes for `FirstName`? which is pointless since only the first one will be bound. Why would you be asking the user to repeat the same data?

Comment: The accordion has two parts that drop down and I was going to have two forms, and two submit buttons. The idea was on one of the accordions where it says 'register as a client' you only fill in firstname, surname, email etc, and to register as a tradesmen you would click the bottom accordion and the same details to be collected are firstname, surname, email but also some other information (as above). Can I only have one forename control, one surname control etc or can I somehow use two of the FormMethod.Post parts and send a different form depending on which has been submitted? Thanks

Comment: You should have one view model, and one form and one post method (the view model would have `[RequiredIf]` attributes based on the selected option is necessary. In thepost method, you can check the value of the selected option, and if a 'tradesmen', then save the additional details to your other table.

Comment: Not quite sure why you have an 'accordion'. You should just show/hide the group of additional controls for 'tradesmen' based on the value of the selected option (although if there are only 2 options (client or tradesperson) then radio buttons or a checkbox seems more appropriate that a dropdownlist

Comment: Excellent, think I'm envisioning the approach you've mentioned and adding some jquery to hide the additional tradesmen fields, many thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `<label>` twice is fine, but I assume you must then have the associated `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)` duplicated as well, which is not fine because (1) it generates duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html and (2) the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the value if the first input with `name="FirstName"`.

There is no reason to repeat the controls. Instead decorate the view model properties associated with your `CompanyModel` with conditional validation attributes (for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`) so they are required if the user is also a tradesman. Since you have indicate the user can either be a tradesman or not, I suggest a `bool` property to generate a checkbox. Your view model would then look like

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    // Properties associated with ApplicationUser
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
    public bool IsTradesPerson { get; set; }
    // Properties associated with CompanyModel
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [RequiredIfTrue("IsTradesPerson", ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and in the view, place the controls associated with `CompanyModel` model in a hidden `<div>` element so that its visibility can be toggled based on the `IsTradesPerson` property

```
<div id="usercontrols">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsTradesperson)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m.IsTradesperson)
</div>
<div id="tradespersoncontrols" hidden>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyName)
    ....
<div>
```

and the script to toggle the visibility

```
var controls = $('tradespersoncontrols');
$('#IsTradesperson').click(function) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        controls.show();
    } else {
        controls.hide();
    }
});
```

Then in the POST method you can check `if(model.IsTradesperson)` and if so, create your `CompanyModel` based on the view model properties and save it.

Comment: Sorry only just noticed this extremely helpful response, thank you very much for your input and time :)